# Deploy WPF Project to UAT and Prod Environment

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, deployment

I am trying to enable the software tester to  install 2 versions of the same application (one UAT  and the other Production) on the same computer. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and the exe(installer) is created using ClickOnce. I was able to publish 2 versions to a directory, however, when the tester would try to install the second version it would overwrite the previous version. I did  some research and found out that I had to rename the assembly. However, if I rename the assembly , I get the following error
 "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"
Inner Exception : Could not load file or assembly 'xxx, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"xxx, Culture=neutral"}

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding , changing the namespace and I have absolutely no idea where I am going wrong. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are differences between the 2 versions and they point to different databases

Comment: The user acceptance will have more features and once the end user approves of the features in the UAT, they will be migrated to the Production environment

Comment: Yes, the tester will need to be able to access both

Comment: How do I change the namespace of the XAML view , I tried changing the Default Namespace (in the project -> application window) and that did not work.